# nodemon app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting cmd

Tags: node.js, npm

**After installing** *nodemon package i am getting error nodemon app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting* when saving files.

Comment: It’s impossible to know what’s happening without you showing the code.

Comment: add some code snippets...

Answer (score 0):

This means there is an error somewhere in your code, which is stated above the `[nodemon] app crashed` error. When this error is fixed, nodemon will restart and run properly.

E.g

```
console.l()
        ^

TypeError: console.l is not a function // your actual error
    at Object.<anonymous> (.../app.js:53:9) // line of the error in your file (usually)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:79:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: after re-starting server then it is working properly.

Comment: what exactly is your question, then?

Comment: add code example

Comment: before i was not re-starting server having installing nodemon that's why i am getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because of all the running server processes in the background. So all you need to do is stop them from the terminal.

Quick trick

FOR LINUX

Kill them all by running this on the terminal:

```
pkill -f node
```

And then restart nodemon.

FOR Windows

```
 1. Go to the task manager
 2. Then look for Node.js: Server-side JavaScript
 3. Then right-click on it and End the task from the processes.
```

Then restart the server. It will work fine.